# Python Selenium Web Driver Pass Integer Variable in Url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python \ Selenium \ Chrome driver to perform webscraping.  I want to pass an INT variable (id) to a URL - how do I do this? I have tried all the below but Python errors on this line:

```
  id = 2000
  
  # Part 1: Customer:
  #urlg = 'https://mythirteen.co.uk/customerRest/show/?id=2000' working but need to pass variable
  #urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=' %(id)
  #urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={id}' 
  # urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id='.format(id)
  # urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id='+id
  # urlg = "https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=".format(id)
  # urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=' % id
  driver.get(urlg)
```

I receive errors such as:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I know it its not a string though - id is INT.

Ultimately, I will need to loop through and increase the id + 1 each time, but for now I just want to be able pass the actual variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to concatenate strings and integer, for most methods you have to cast the integer to a string with `str(id)`.

Otherwise I really like using f-strings:

```
urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={id}'
```

**Edit**
As @chitown88 mentioned, using `id` as a variable is not a good idea, as it is reserved internally. Better use something like `customer_id`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the methods you are trying is you essentially aren't telling it where to put the string, or trying to concat a string and an int

so this `'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=' %(id)` needs to be `'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=%s' %(id)`

So all these would work:

Also, I would not use `id` as the variable, as it's a reserved function in python. It also could make more sense to make it more descriptive:

```
customerId = 2000

urlg = 'https://mythirteen.co.uk/customerRest/show/?id=2000' working but need to pass variable
urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=%s' %(customerId)
urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id=%s' %customerId
urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={customerId}' 
urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={}'.format(customerId)
urlg = 'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id='+str(customerId)
```